# How to publish over ssh in multibranch pipeline in jenkins

Tags: maven, spring-boot, jenkins, multibranch-pipeline

I have maven springboot project with Jenkinsfile at root. I have written stages in jenkins file to build jar file and it's working fine.Next stage is 'deployment' where i have to move jar file to Linux server and run it there. Could anyone please help me with stage in jenkinsfile how to move jar file from Jenkins server to another server and run it there.

Comment: do you ran plain jar files or docker for deployments?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1.you can use the Publish over SSH plugin and get the syntax for Pipeline syntax

```
sshPublisher(publishers: [sshPublisherDesc(configName: 'SERVER_to_be_deployed', transfers: [sshTransfer(excludes: '', execCommand: '', execTimeout: 120000, flatten: false, makeEmptyDirs: false, noDefaultExcludes: false, patternSeparator: '[, ]+', remoteDirectory: '', remoteDirectorySDF: false, removePrefix: '', sourceFiles: '**/target/*.war')], usePromotionTimestamp: false, useWorkspaceInPromotion: false, verbose: false)])
```

2.you can just use a scp command to transfer files across machines

```
scp [options] username1@source_host:directory1/filename1 username2@destination_host:directory2/filename2
```

3.curl to do the same

```
curl -u username:password -T /path/to/file.txt sftp://host.com:22/file.txt
```

Which one would you like to use :)

Comment: @Madhu Sudhan Reddy if this helped you in solving your issue please select it as the correct answer so that others, who face this issue will know what needs to be done