# Triggering a script in windows system from Jenkins in Linux server

Tags: java, linux, jenkins, selenium-webdriver

I have a java program in a windows system and I need Jenkins job from my company Linux server to trigger the java program in windows machine.

The Java project is automation script built in selenium and can be converted to JAR file to invoke using Java -jar  command.

But I am confused how to trigger jenkins job from Linux server to execute the Jar file in windows machine. Can someone tried this help me on this scenario?

Comment: Easy just do an SSH from Linux  to Windows, once connection is set run your java command

    Java -jar SeliumTest

Comment: Thanks for the answer @rohitthomas. After setting the connection how do I mention the path of jar file in the remote windows system from Jenkins(in Linux server). I am creating a freestyle project and how do I invoke the jar?

Comment: use the  SSH over plugin....https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Publish+Over+SSH+Plugin If you want to do it using pipeline then follow this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50376212/how-to-publish-over-ssh-in-multibranch-pipeline-in-jenkins/50403660#50403660... hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks @rohitthomas, I will post result after trying this option.

Comment: I tried this from windows machine to Linux and worked well.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create master-slave in Jenkin.

Master would be your linux server Jenkin and configure as slave your window machine because your suite gonna run on WIndow machine.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @ankitgupta. After setting the connection how do I mention the path of jar file in the remote windows system from Jenkins(in Linux server). I am creating a freestyle project and how do I invoke the jar?

Comment: Once you done with the master-slave configuration then simple use shell execution or you can create a .bat file to run this. The better option which I choose create .bat file in a program hit that java file using Java or if you use Maven project then using pom.xml.

Comment: Thanks @ankitgupta.Will try this and post the results.